# How to play a video inside a logo

Tags: html, css

how can i play a image inside a logo like [this website](http://thelawofthejungle.com/)

you can see the video playing inside the law of the jungle logo how can i do that in css or html? I don't know where to start.

Comment: Are you planning to do it with css? Because that will be difficult. This is quite advanced graphics so you might have the check  [graphics exchange](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably just use 2 divs. The top on is all white except the part what the logo is, that part should be empty (a png). You put the video in the div behind it. You can do that with z-index. That could give you the same effect.